# Can't deploy WAR file using manager-gui

Tags: tomcat

I dont quite understand. I am unable to deploy WAR files using the web manager web interface / Select WAR file to deploy...

I keep running into "403 Access Denied".

I was pretty sure my tomcat-users.xml was okay. I've logged into the manager using the manager account:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="mypass" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="manager" password="mypass" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
  <user username="admin" password="mypass" roles="admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

My Tomcat's webapps folder is as folllow:

`drwxrwxr-x 7 tomcat9 tomcat9 4.0K Oct  4 16:09 /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps`

And my running regular user's account is a member of group tomcat9.

Which other rights am I missing here ?

P.s. As my running user account, I've tried just copying my .war file directly into my webapps folder and it auto-deployed just fine, AND, I can undeploy it from the manager-gui! I would much prefer to do it all with the web interface.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: output of the only log I see in:

```
/var/log/tomcat9/localhost_access_log.2020-10-04.txt 


0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [04/Oct/2020:16:49:55 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11216
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [04/Oct/2020:16:50:07 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2499
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - manager [04/Oct/2020:16:50:12 +0200] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 19412
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [04/Oct/2020:16:50:12 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - manager [04/Oct/2020:16:50:28 +0200] "POST /manager/html/upload;jsessionid=408C34653F3324F39466280BEA5BE4D9?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=0CF4932EB9CDF4B604786FAC651FFACB HTTP/1.1" 200 18254
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - manager [04/Oct/2020:16:50:28 +0200] "POST /manager/html/upload;jsessionid=408C34653F3324F39466280BEA5BE4D9?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=0CF4932EB9CDF4B604786FAC651FFACB HTTP/1.1" 403 3446
```

Pat

Comment: is there no extra informationin any of the logs?

Comment: Nothing at all! See my edit..

Comment: try setting `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = ALL` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` src: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and have found a solution:
This issue is caused by war file size limit set in the manager's web.xml.
So just increase the allowed size and it should work